# No handlers could be found for logger "pika.adapters.blocking_connection"

Tags: python, amqp, pika

Similar questions all seem to be based around using a custom logger, I'm happy to just use the default / none at all. My pika python app runs and receives messages but after a few seconds crashes with `No handlers could be found for logger "pika.adapters.blocking_connection"`, any ideas?

```
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxx_apphb.com', 'xxx')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('bunny.cloudamqp.com', 5672, 'xxx_apphb.com', credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare('messages')

def message_received(channel, method, properties, body):
    print "[x] Received %r" % (body)

channel.basic_consume(message_received, queue='messages', no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Fixed by adding:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when I upgraded from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6 and my issue was my rabbit service was being killed off. I had to change from inittab to initctl to launch my python scripts, after that rabbit didn't die. Figured I'd share my comment in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 30):

Fixed by adding:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

Comment: It helps me when I tried to use pika in python console. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There should be exchange name provide, it should not left default.

```
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='anyname')
```